# why i can type only one char in DrRacket?

Tags: racket

It can  type only one char.
look like a bug. 
I  am   using       fc6.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a question, so it shouldn't have been posted here.  It's not even clear what is the bug that you're having (we're running it on Fedora 7 with no problem) -- better to provide a fuller description and use the [Racket mailing lists](http://racket-lang.org/community.html) or post it as a bug in the [Racket bug database](http://bugs.racket-lang.org/).